# Model View Controller and Callbacks

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm currently developing a multiplayer cardgame for android, with libgdx as the game engine. My question is more generel tho.

I'm not sure whats the best practice for handling callbacks in this architecture. My controller is a big statemachine, that checks inputs over and over while beeing called from the render() method of the gameengine.

I have two main callbacks, userinput from the gui, and network callbacks from the android google play services part.

Currently these callback methode/ inputListeners just set member variables, which are check by getter methods from the controller/statemachine, for example i call this from the controller over and over, check if its != null and proceed if it is.

```
@Override
public Boolean allPlayersConnected() {
    Boolean allConnected = null;
    if (startGame != null) {
        allConnected = startGame;
        startGame = null;
    }
    return allConnected;

}
```

The startGame "flag" beeing set by callbacks from the google play services api.

I dont know if this is good practice, doesnt look like.

I could call controller methods from the google play services callbacks that set a controller member variable, and check this in each render loop, but thats just moving the variable.

I could also design the controller as an observer of those events, but what am i going to do in the update method inside the controller thats beeing called if an event happens. i dont think i want change stats in these, even if i can access the currrent state. Im spreading state code all over the place with this, some in different parts of a huge update method and some in the actual state machine code. Just setting a member variable in the update method is quite similar to the think i did above.

Another thing would be, to directly change controller state from the callback methods. That would be less code, less variables and a little faster, but i think i'd destroy the MVP concept, cause i take away the control from the controller and let i.e. the gui change the state of the controller.

Any input on this ?

Edit:

The more i think about it, the more i think a combination of observer and command pattern is the way to go.

So i could indeed cut big part of the current state machine and pack it into the observer update() method. Instead of sending the commands through a big command enum, i could create command object with the information available, and pass them to the observer(controller), where i check the command as viable, and call the execute with the information needed to be excecuted, eg the model interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think whether your commands are enums or command objects is independent of the main problem here -- which is how to connect user and network input to state management.

The most common game architecture I've seen is an update loop that checks input, iterates the game simulation, and then renders a frame. In the MVC world, this structure just synchronizes those steps; you still have an encapsulated view and data model, with the controller (the game loop) serving as a a bridge between those two worlds.

Input, whether from the local user or one over the net, is generally treated as a request to modify game state. That is, the controller (as the first part of its loop) reads in pending input messages and processes them, modifying state as it goes. This way, the code that changes state is in one place: that controller. You are right, spreading state-modification code throughout the app is a bad practice; basically, it's not MVC.

In other words, all of your callbacks should convert the input to commands and stick them into a queue. You don't want to synchronize the controller -- whose job it is to modify state -- with those input callbacks. You have no idea when input will occur relative to the game loop, so it's best to decouple them. Serializing input processing with game simulation should also make your logic simpler.

You have some choice in how to connect the callbacks to the controller; a shared queue (where one side writes into it and the other reads out from it) is a strong pattern and easy to make thread-safe.

Comment: Thnks for the answer, everything seems a little clearer now. I think the most important part is the synchronize part. I dont want the callback (observer update method) to immediately execute the command, cause i dont know where the current proccess is working and when inputs occur. Maybe one more question: Besides the command queue, that i fill in the observer update method, and from which the controller takes the commands when its time, what other Options do i have to keep everything syncronized, and the controller in control?

Comment: It really depends on the commands that you have, but a command queue is used in tons of places, including Windows. You can search on "event-driven programming" for more info. Systems that run off a limited input system, such as a gamepad or the industrial equivalent, will usually just store the state of the pad in one object and let the controller decide how to interpret it.